# I want to test my tool functionality using github actions

Tags: github, installation, github-actions

I have a tool which needs to be installed and check if it working in a desired way or not. I want to do it using github actions. Is there any way to install the tool on the github actions triggered VM machine and run a piece of code on that tool to test it?

Comment: Could you please add more context to your question. A quick answer to your question is: yes if you can run this tool on your local machine using some CLI. Github actions currently provide ubuntu, windows, and macos runners. And don't confuse it with a VM where you can install some tool for a prolonged period. It is a CI environment.

Comment: @RobinRaju Yeah! I recently found the features and usability of docker images. I am planning to build an image for the whole repo and run my test cases on the tool. Do you have any other solutions for it?